# Generate sum variable for subgroups

Tags: stata, dummy-variable

I have here a Steam Dataset which includes individual steam user and their playtimes(overall) and the games they played. I further divided the player in hardcore(=1) and casual player (=0). Overall I want to test how various factors have influence on the overall playtime of the players, but now I want to build 2 regressions, one for hardcore players and one for casual players(because I think that the effect of every factor can differ between those two). But in order to do that, I need the sum of the overall playtime from the 2 subgroups. I tried `egen playtime_type = sum(playtime_sum), by (hightype)`, but the outcome just doesn't make sense. How can I aggregate the sum of playtime only for each subgroup?

Here is a example from the dataset

```
steamid playtime_sum    hightype
76561197960265729   0   0
76561197960265730   45  0
76561197960265730   45  0
76561197960265730   45  0
76561197960265733   1710    0
76561197960265733   1710    0
76561197960265733   1710    0
76561197960265733   1710    0
76561197960265733   1710    0
76561197960265738   11  0
76561197960265738   11  0
76561197960265738   11  0
```

Answer (score 1):

What makes sense and what does not make sense is highly subjective and it is always better if you explain what the output was and what you had expected instead.

My guess is that you want to use `total()` instead of `sum()`.

`egen playtime_type = total(playtime_sum), by(hightype)`

Comment: maybe create a new question with that question. Be specific. Include an example data set using `dataex` (see here https://stackoverflow.com/tags/stata/info), and calculate for that example dataset the results variable manually that you want. Then use equations to express what regression you want. If you want help with the statistics on how to define your regressions, then https://stats.stackexchange.com/ is a more appropriate place to ask

Comment: Thank you very much! I figured it out!

Comment: `sum()` is just the old name for `total()` and nothing hinges on the difference. So, OP, what was the explanation?  A question without a solution is not much help for any future reader.

Comment: I wondered why/how `sum()` works when its undocumented.

Comment: It's undocumented but its code is perfectly accessible: try `which _gsum` in your Stata.